# Fixed effects in R for a Stata user

Tags: r, stata, panel-data

I've looked for a similar question but haven't yet found exactly what I'm looking for.

In Stata, I can run the model below with panel data (school and time fixed effects):

```
xi: areg total i.year*group_dummy, absorb(school) cluster (school)
```

How would I run the similar regression in R using the `plm` package?

This is what I tried:

```
model1 <- plm(total ~ group_dummy, 
          na.action = na.omit,
          data   = pdlong, 
          method = "within",
          index = c("school", "year"),
          effect = "twoway")
```

But I get an error message (and am unsure how this should be interpreted):

Error in x[, ii] : subscript out of bounds

Comment: Not an answer at all, but the `xi:` syntax has been redundant (indeed is deprecated) as of Stata 11 (2009).

Comment: @Roland Seems to me that the Stata tag is applicable: 1. Stata code is included.  2. The question hinges on translating Stata into R, so the more users of both softwares are alerted to this, the better. (I don't use R enough to answer.)

Comment: @NickCox My view is that the Stata aspect is irrelevant here. The question is about an error returned by an R function (and lacks a reproducible example). Even if it was purely about translation, it would be better if a language agnostic explanation was included instead of Stata code. Translation questions are usually "too broad".

Comment: @Roland I think translation questions are often problematic. I don't see that they are necessarily too broad, as often they are based on specific code. I am just suggesting that the Stata tag remains, but I won't fight if someone removes it.

Comment: @NickCox I was able to solve the problem by using the lfm package, and the felm command as shown below. In a sense, solving the problem in this manner doesn't respond to the initial question unless the question is viewed as a translation question...

    fixedef <- felm(total ~ as.factor(year)*group, 
                na.action = na.omit,
                data   = pdlong)